# How to implement horizontal scroll? - windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have this code working already but I want to change the scrolling to horizontal.
Im pretty new working with windows phone. Please any help will be appreciated.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,139,12,0">
        <ListBox Name="lbLogros" Margin="0,10,-10,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="160" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                        <Image Width="140" Source="{Binding Path=rutaImagen}" />
                        <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40" Text="{Binding Path=nombre}" Style="{StaticResource MainSubtitle}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontSize="20" Width="290" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource MainText}">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget purus ligula.
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your visibility, it works in my case.

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

Answer (score 0):

To control how items are arranged within `ListBox` control or other similar controls, play with the `ItemsPanel` property. For example, using horizontal `VirtualizingStackPanel` for `ItmsPanel` will cause the items to be arranged horizontally :

```
<ListBox Name="lbLogros" Margin="0,10,-10,0" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        .....
        .....
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```